# Intercept all key on Xiaomi Pad 5 with physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard, xiaomi, external-keyboard, macos

I'm trying to create a remote workplace with:

- AnyDesk
- MacBook
- Xiaomi Pad 5
- Logitech MX key.

On a Mac, I enabled a keyboard assistant to track keystrokes.
AnyDesk on both devices.

The keyboard works fine when connected to Macbook.

Result:
Keys (letters, numbers, enter) work fine.
Changing the layout works fine,

Ctrl = Ctrl;
Opt = Opt;
Cmd = Opt;

But if I launch the built-in virtual keyboard in AnyDesk, then pressing Cmd is intercepted correctly on the Macbook.

The Cmd + Tab combinations are intercepted by the tablet, like other Cmd-related combinations. (the tablet interprets them as Opt + button)
When hold opt, I see "Show app dock", and shortcut - hold Cmd.

The question is how to correctly intercept ALL combinations from the physical keyboard?

I tried changing the layout, downloading others, but nothing changed.

Comment: I tried to replace the tablet with an old iphone. Everything worked the first time. Too bad the phone screen is small